# Static IP for a adhoc wifi network

Tags: airport, network, ad-hoc

Do you know if it's possible to give a static IP when creating a ad-hoc network on OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, to actually do much in ad-hoc mode you even have to setup static IP addresses.

Just start the ad-hoc network, then in System Preferences -> Network "Click the lock to make changes" and then click "Advanced". And there you have it.

[image: System Preferences, Manual TCP/IP settings]